# Making Scales on a Dragon

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I'm trying to make a dragon for 3D printing.  I've previously made similar creatures by making a single scale, then, through a long series of Array and Curve modifiers, have created my dragon body (as described here: http://objectforge.blogspot.com/2019/01/new-thing-drakes.html).  I'm looking to improve the process though for my latest dragon.

My chief complaint with my current process is that I am ultimately making a "scale tube" out of perfectly formed scales, then putting it on a curve via the Curve modifier, which distorts those scales around bends in the dragon's pose, as you see here:
[image]

What I really want is for the scales to just clip through each other or separate as needed by the curve, rather than distort (I'll make sure that there's a solid tube inside the scale tube so that it's printable).

The closest thing that I can think of to doing this would be to make a big array of curve circles and Curve that array onto my dragon's body curve.  Then I could manually put a row of scales onto each of those circles via Curve modifiers on those rows of scales.  Given the number of rows on this whole dragon though, that sounds tedious to the point of impossibility.  Do any of you bright folks have better ideas about how I can get my scales into a properly dragonish shape?

Comment: Have you tried using a particle system? You could have a scale for each vertex on your model, if it was me I'd definitely try to do it this way rather than with arrays. Other solution is to do them directly in sculpt mode with a texture, a bit more tedious if your texture only have a couple of scales on it.

Comment: @Arthur-Blaquart Can you point me at any good resources for particle systems?  Every time I've tried to use one, I end up chaos.  First, I seem to get a completely random assortment of my particles (I'm not sure how to get them onto the vertices).  Second, I can't get them oriented so that they follow the line of the curve (so scales might look good on the tail but look terrible on the body).  Do you know how to resolve those two issues?

Comment: Oh, I think I see how to do it now.  Under Emission, I can change "Emit From" to Verts and disable "Random Order".  Under Render I can select my scale object and scale it appropriately (the use of the word "scale" like this is one reason this has been so difficult to google!).  Then, I had to enable the Rotation section and change the Orientation Axis to Velocity / Hair.

After I set that all up, I went into Particle Edit mode and combed the hairs so that they were all pointed the right way.  Thanks for pointing me at this solution, I'm super happy with the results!

Comment: Yep you got it exactly right! You are welcome.